# How SEO friendly is Unicode URL?

Tags: url, unicode, seo

As the title says, how SEO friendly is a URL containing Unicode characters.

**Edit**: To clarify, I meant URL with non-ASCII characters but valid Unicode.

Answer (score 5):

If I were a Google other search engines authority I wouldn't consider the unicode URL-s an advantage. I have been using unicode urls for more than two years in my Persian website but believe me I just did it because I felt I was forced to do this. We know Google handles Uncode urls very well but I can't see the unicode words in URL-s when I'm working with them in google webmaster tools here is an example:

http://www.learnfast.ir/%D9%88%D8%A8%D9%84%D8%A7%DA%AF-%D8%A2%DA%AF%D9%87%DB%8C

there are only two Farsi words in such a messy and lengthy URL. 
I believe other Unicode url users don't like this either but they do this only for SEO optimization not for categorizing their contents or directing their users to the right address. Of course unicode is excellent for crawling the contents but there should be other ways to index URL-s. more over, English is our international language; Isn't it? It can be beneficially used for URL-s. There should be other means for indexing Unicode Urls. (Sorry for too much words from an amateur webmaster).

Answer (score 4):

All URLs can be represented as Unicode. Unicode just defines a range of code-points from U+0000 to U+10FFFF, which allows you to define any characters.

If what you mean is "How SEO friendly are URLs containing characters above U+007F" then they should be as good as anything else, as long as the word is correct. However, they won't be very easy for most users to type if that's a concern, and may not be supported by all internet browsers/libraries/proxies etc. so I'd tend to steer clear.

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, Amazon (Japan) uses Unicode URL for their product pages.

[http://www.amazon.co.jp/任天堂-193706011-Wiiスポーツ-リゾート-「Wiiモーションプラス」1個同梱/dp/B001DLXXCC/ref=pd_bxgy_vg_img_a](http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E4%BB%BB%E5%A4%A9%E5%A0%82-193706011-Wii%E3%82%B9%E3%83%9D%E3%83%BC%E3%83%84-%E3%83%AA%E3%82%BE%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88-%E3%80%8CWii%E3%83%A2%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%83%97%E3%83%A9%E3%82%B9%E3%80%8D1%E5%80%8B%E5%90%8C%E6%A2%B1/dp/B001DLXXCC/ref=pd_bxgy_vg_img_a)

(As you can see, it causes trouble with systems like the Stackoverflow wiki formatter)

Comment: Not from my machine. Your machine probably doesn't have Unicode support installed.

Answer (score 3):

if we consider that the urls that have the searched keywords in them have higher placements in the search results and you're targeting unicode search terms then it may actually help. 
But of course this is hardly the most important thing when it comes to position in search results.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess from an SEO point of view it would be a really bad idea, unless you are specifically looking to target unicode search terms.

Comment: @bukzor Why not? SEO is pretty much all educated guesswork as the search engines do not publish their ranking algorithms