# SEO-friendly URL param with foreign encoded characters?

Tags: url, url-rewriting, seo, title

I would like a URL pattern as such:

```
/posts/[postId]/[user-defined-page-title]
```

My users are Potuguese speakers, however, and the page title could have characters such as `ã`, `ç`, etc...

Posts are retrieved via the `postId` param, so the `title` param is for SEO and usability purposes.

**My questions:**

1. Should I remove the foreign encoded characters and replace them with their nearest English equivalent? `ç` for `c` and `ã` for `a`.
2. Does doing so affect SEO results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes, that would be the best way (at least nowadays -- but situation may change in few years...)

2) Hard to say for sure. In my opinion  having latin characters only is better compared to have national characters as well (as they need to be encoded). At the end of the day page title and content has more weight than URL itself.

P.S. See this link as well: [How SEO friendly is Unicode URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176944/how-seo-friendly-is-unicode-url)