# Unicode url of website and seo issue

Tags: url, seo

I am working on a persina website. i want to change url structure of pages to be more seo friendly.but i don't know using unicode urls will have positive effect on SEO of website or not.

The pages unicode is UTF-8 . When i copy the link location in firefox and paste it in address bar something like this (for example) will appears:

http://mysite.com/pages/36161-%D8%B4%DB%8C%D9%85%D9%89.html

it is ok with search engines and seo ?

Comment: No good answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176944/how-seo-friendly-is-unicode-url ?

Comment: The Unicode renders properly in Chrome, it would appear to be a limitation of the browser version you are using.

Comment: so ,how the search engine spider will read it? will they understand such this link?

Answer (score 3):

I encountered a similar problem on my site after a few tests and a long time I have concluded that Google deal well with these addresses and you have no reason to worry.

In my case the URLs was in Hebrew and there is not much difference between the two languages for Googlebot.
The major problems i has was with URLs in the site map they looked really bad, but google still indexed them.

Is this transition will be good for seo? I guess you it will but do not allow friendly URLs confuse you is only one criterion and there is no reason to trust him.
You get +1 on friendly URLs but there's no reason to forget about the rest of the onsite site Seo.
It is very important that you redirect the old URLs with 301 redirect to the new ones.
To not receive a 401 error that will cause you to be punished by the search engines

Comment: thank you.but which one is prefered? user friendly url or seo friendly url? normal urls or ugly urls?